# Allow specific weak cipher in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, tls, cipher

I have to connect to a system that uses a weak TLS cipher :
[TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA](https://ciphersuite.info/cs/TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA/).

This is an embedded web server in a physical appliance and there is no firmware available to change that cipher. The only solution provided by the manufacturer is "Disable TLS". For (obvious) security reasons, this is not an option.

When I try to connect with Chrome, I receive "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR".

Is there any way to tell Chrome that I want to allow that specific cipher ?

Comment: Why not use Firefox?

Comment: It was our solution, but since a few month, this cipher is blocked in Firefox too. We have now switched to Pale Moon, but I guess it's just a matter of time before this one won't work either.